# REST-API calls from Angular ngResource-Service not forwarded by Reverse-Proxy

Tags: node.js, angularjs, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure two Node-based Angular.js applications behind a reverse proxy (tried mod-proxy for Apache and also Nginx). Let me explain:

Application A runs on `localhost:3000`
Application B runs on `localhost:3001`
Application A should be visible from outside on `http://myServer/appA`
Application B should be visible from outside on `http://myServer/appB`

The problem is, that regular resources (index.html, images, js-files) are loaded, but calls to the REST-API using the Angular ngResource-Service don't work.

Some investigations using Fiddler pointed out, that for loading the regular resources, the proper URL is used (e.g. `http://myServer/appA/image.png`) but for the REST-calls the URL is missing the /appA path (e.g. `http://myServer/data` is called instead of `http://myServer/appA/data`).

Dos anybody know, how I can fix this? Is it possible to make a configuration on the Angular ngResurce-Service. Or is it a server-side issue which must be fixed by doing the appropriate settings for proxy-html or mod-proxy.

Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the problem: it was our own error in using the Angular resource service. We included a leading / in the paths for the REST-calls, e.g. /machines. With this leading / all URLs are interpreted absolut, e.g. `http://myServer/machines` is called instead of `http://myServer/appA/machines` .